# Is it possible to push the modified css or js file without changing static version number into the customer browser?

Tags: magento2, php, cache, static-content-deploy, browser

At present when we modify the JS or CSS file, the only way to update the Customers browser is to change the sign for static files globally by running `static-content:deploy` or at most we can give `--no-css` or `--no-javascript` option for css or js respectively. Now my question is can we change the version number for the file only which was modified, like suppose i changed **Test_Example::web/css/test.css** file, then only **test.css** file changes should be pushed to the customers browser. Please give me solution for this requirement if anyone has already done this similar kind of solution. The reason for this requirement is that using the `static-content:deploy` totally flushes the customer cache files as the version number changes, and it takes time for the data to load into cache of the customer when he loads the site for first time after `static-content:deploy` command ran.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the signing of static files. Go to: `Stores > Configuration > Advanced > Developer > Static files setting` and set `Sign static files` to no. After that, it doesn't generate a static content version number. That should do the trick.

Comment: I am aware of this option, but i think this option will stop loading the changed files from the server and use the old cached files only. Every time it will load everything from browser cache instead of loading from the from the server even if the changes are made to particular css or js file at the server end.